# Can I Task.Delay() for 1 day?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I need to do some cleanups in my DB once every day. I'm using a `BackgroundService`:

```
public class DbCleanerService : BackgroundService
{    
    public DbCleanerService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // get a db context and do the cleanup

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any gotchas that I'm not aware of? Will the long delay cause any problem? For example I've read on many places that this is not safe for IIS hosted websites because IIS might shutdown its unused websites. (I'm not using IIS though)

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 with Kestrel on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Comment: I would say it should be perfectly fine though you need to handle crash/redeployment scenarios (unless you are fine with multiple invocations per day) and possibly control the time of invocation - I assume you don't want to clear the DB during peek loads if those exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your actual question. Task.Delay *can* be used to delay up to int.MaxValue. So yes, your code is OK.

Now as you've pointed out, IIS can wind down websites if you aren't careful, but also during redeployment scenarios, your application will restart and you don't have any way (in your existing code), to track where you are up to. In those scenarios, using something like Hangfire would be better.

**However**, assuming your DB Cleaner service is fine to be run multiple times per day (e.g. It just cleans up old records and is not *required* to be run once and only once per day), then you might not even care.